# using the len() function to get the length of a date in access VBA

Tags: vba, ms-access

I am writing a function which takes a date and converts into a string of characters so i can use that string of characters to save an export file.  so 12/10/2019 becomes 12102019.

I ran into a problem and i believe I may not be using the len() function correctly.

I wanted to ensure that single digit months and days, ie 1/1/2019 appeared as this 01012019

I created a loop to go through an entire calendar year to test my function.

```
dim x as date

if len(x) = 8 then
     debug.print x
elseif len(x) = 9 then
     debug.print x
end if
```

imagine this is in a loop.

when len(x) = 8, no problem. i get the date ie 1/1/2019
when len(x) = 9, ie 1/10/2019, it won't process the elseif.

am i using the len() function correctly?  is there something else i should be using?

thanks

Groundhog

Comment: Save yourself the trouble and just format the date to a string - `Format$(x, "mmddyyyy")` - then the length is always the same and already in the format you need.

Comment: Better yet, save yourself some future headaches and change the format of your export files to `yyyymmdd`, which will allow you to properly sort them using `dir` or Explorer. If you're not sure why, create some sample text files in a folder like `01012019.txt`, `02012018.txt` and various dates in different months and years and then try to list them in chronological order.

Comment: Thanks, I will use the format method.  I hadn't thought about that but appreciate the help

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`len()` in VBA will give you the length of the date. In VBA many data types are actually stored as doubles under the hood. That's why you're not seeing the String length of the date, but the length of the number of digits in the `doubles` value.

You can test this in excel, these dates:

1/1/2019
1/10/2019

When formatted as Numbers (5 digits length):

43466
43739

To fix it you can follow @braX & Ken's advice with `Format$(x, "yyyymmdd")`, you could enclose in quotes and deduct 2 from the length, or cast the dates and work with them as strings in VBA.